# Store file into SQL Server Using React and Node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, blob, buffer

I'm having a problem. I need to store a file into the **SQL server** using **Node.js** as backend and **React.js** as frontend but don't know how to do this. Actually, I'm having experience with Multer but I strictly need to store the file into SQL DB. I tried but it stores just a few bytes into DB instead of the complete file.

Also please let me know how can we access files from the DB and download it to the browser when the user clicks on Download.

**Note:** I access the file in blob form

```
// Frontend Action

   this.props.postNewAccountAttachment({
      acta_act_key: '598806',
      acta_file_name: this.state.fileName,
      acta_description: this.state.description,
      acta_attachment: this.state.attachment,
   });
```

```
//Backend API Services
async postAccountAttachment(attachmentBody) {
    const attachment = await this.models.account_attachments.create(
      attachmentBody
    );
    return attachment;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge and experience, you should not store the actual file in SQLDB, instead upload the file to a separate folder in server and store file information into the database.

i.e(Filename, Type , Size )

To store file info into DB :

```
 var sql = "INSERT INTO `file`(`name`, `type`, `size`) VALUES ('" + req.file.filename + "', '"+req.file.mimetype+"', '"+req.file.size+"')";

 var query = db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
       console.log('File Information Saved');
 });
```